# escape '<' inside <tr> tag in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, tr, html-escape-characters

I have a field Value for segmentations as `<Value TBD>`, which is not getting printed in the HTML table.

This is the way I'm trying to populate the value:

```
  if($("th[data-field='rating']").get(0) !== undefined) {
      debugger;
    row.append($("<td />").css("font-size", "12px").html(""+segmentations+""));
  }
```

It is taking other normal character values like 'Adoption' but not able to print `<Value TBD>`. Is there any way to escape this '<' characters inside `</tr>` tag?

Comment: Should be `($("<td></td>")`

Comment: Does `segmentations` actually contain HTML or just text? If there's just text, use the `text()` method instead. It fhere's HTML, stop putting things that looks like an element in the text.

Comment: yes, it contains HTML tags Entyvio (Customer Belief:<Values TBD>)<br />, If i only use .text(""+segmentations+"") without .html(), it will show me  the tags, and if i only use both then the table css is getting disturbed

Comment: sorry, with .html() i'm getting the </br> tag : row.append($("<td></td>").css("font-size", "12px").text(""+segmentations+"").html());

Comment: @LGSon, i tried to use ($("<td></td>") but it is working same as before